# Ache, 'Countable noun' or 'Uncountable noun'?

Tags: nouns

I can usually read the sentence like ' I have a headache.'

But I think 'ache' is kind of the pain. We can't see the pain and touch the pain.

Therefore, I think that it should be 'uncountable noun'.

How can this be 'countable noun'?

Could you explain how it can be counted?

Comment: Being able to see or touch something is not what makes something countable. An idea is countable - "I have three ideas of how to fix this issue." - but you can't see or touch it.

Comment: Oddly, we hardly ever say we have X aches _now_. We usually call them out by name "my head aches, and my back aches, and my knee is sore too."  Or we generalize the count:  "I have lots of aches and pains."  But they are definitely countable. Single and plural. Not a group noun. Pain, on the other hand, can be non-count: a doctor might ask "Do you have pain?" but never "Do you have ache?"

Comment: Thank you Brian and Catija. As my country doesn't use English by mother tongue, Uncountable and countable nouns are really hard to understand. But I think I can catch the difference between 'ache' and 'pain'. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people consider a headache to be an event or an episode.  "I have had three headaches this week, so I went to see a doctor."

Comment: An event re an episode. Then I can understand. Thank you.